# Roughly what date do NSF Postdoc Fellowship announcements occur?

Tags: funding, postdocs, nsf, awards

I can't find any information about when NSF announces the recipients of their postdoctoral fellowship awards. I'm specifically interested in the one for mathematics. I'd like to use this information to get a rough schedule for rolling applications.

Comment: What do you mean by rolling applications?  If you're thinking about deciding whether to apply for more postdocs after hearing about the NSF, it comes out too late for that.  The NSF is announced after the application deadlines for a lot of jobs, so you need to plan and apply under the assumption that you won't get the NSF.

Comment: There are many jobs that are not postdocs, and places like industry labs often have rolling applications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In another answer, Zach H said that notifications for 2014 went out on January 14th.

In 2015, the date was January 26.

In general, the notifications are sent out a week or so before the coordinated postdoc deadline, the day before which most research universities agree not to require a decision on postdoc offers. http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination  This deadline changes from year to year, but it is always toward the end of January/beginning of February.

The idea is that people should have an opportunity to find out whether they've received the NSF before making any other decisions on postdoc offers, and if they were not one of the lucky few getting the NSF, then they should have at least a week to mull over their decision.

Answer (score 7):

In 2020, the informal notifications were sent out on January 26 (a Friday).

For 2021, the [AMS](http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination) says the NSF will try to complete the review by January 22. (Most departments will not require a response to their offer by February 1, also according to that page.)

For 2022, the [AMS](http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination) again says "the NSF's Division of Mathematical Sciences has agreed to complete its review of applications and electronically notify all applicants by Friday, January 21, 2022, at the latest."

Comment: Has anyone heard back from the NSF this year? I'm still trying to figure out where my application went. (Two years ago, I didn't get an official rejection until March.)

Answer (score 4):

In 2014 I received an informal notice of rejection for an NSF postdoc in mathematics on January 14th, immediately prior to the Joint Meetings. Acceptance notifications were sent at the same time, though the formal decision was not posted for another eight days. I can't attest to whether this was typical.